# Stringy corrections to Friedmann equation

Tags: general-relativity, string-theory, cosmology, quantum-gravity

Does anyone know a reference or a paper which discusses string theory correction to Friedmann equations?

Comment: Maybe this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0303095v1.pdf) might interest you (see for instance Chapter $5$ page $25$ and formulae $158$-$164$ page $29$)

Comment: As it currently is, the question is too broad, there are many 'corrections' that could be thought as 'stringy'. For an introduction look at the lectures: Cline, J.M. *String cosmology*. [arXiv:hep-th/0612129](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0612129) (2006).